# SOAPUI running test cases determined by user selection

Tags: soapui

I was wondering whether it was possible to allow the user to make a selection from 3 choices and then running a test case based on that user's choice?

For example, I have an end to end test case which orchestrates running a number of test cases, however I would like to put something there like a manual step which asks the user to select 'a', 'b', or 'c' and depending on their selection the corresponding test case would be ran.

I've had a look around and seen a 'Conditional GoTo Step' being mentioned but i can comprehend how to use that in this situation.

Is this possible using the free version of SOAPUI?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: [https://www.soapui.org/functional-testing/controlling-flow.html] (https://www.soapui.org/functional-testing/controlling-flow.html) use this link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in Groovy Script:

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.UISupport
def inputValue = UISupport.prompt("InputValue","Input the Value ")
log.info inputValue
```

Comment: Thansk for this, just wondering how to get the xml from a groovy script to work with Conditional GoTo ? i do not have the pro version so do not have access to a wizard which allows me to do this. many thanks

Comment: [please follow link section 3](https://www.soapui.org/scripting-properties/tips-tricks.html) ; let me know what xml your are talking about ; request; response or reading file